# A way to make inline <div> take all avalible width

Tags: html, css

Frequently solution for this is `float`, but it will not work in my case. I tried to use flexbox, `overflow:hidden` for parent, but it didn't help either.

So I have three inline-block elements. The width of that one in the center is defined by text length in it, but others are just for drawing black line on the sides with known height. Like this:

```css
.headline {
  width: 700px;
}

.headline>* {
  display: inline-block;
}

.blackline {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <div class="blackline"></div>
  <h1>blah blah blah</h1>
  <div class="blackline"></div>
</div>
```

Parent element width is known and constant, but that one in center is variable.

and it should look something like this:
`|---blah blah blah---|`
so that `<h1>` element is always in center and both `<div>` have same width which takes all available space depending on the `<h1>` width as i can't know how many "blah" it will contain.

Comment: This doesn’t need any extra markup ... https://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with flexbox like this:

```css
.headline {
  width: 500px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  border:1px solid;
}

.blackline {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 10px;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <div class="blackline"></div>
  <h1>blah blah blah</h1>
  <div class="blackline"></div>
</div>
```

You can also simplify the markup like this:

```css
.headline {
  width: 500px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  border:1px solid;
}

.headline:before,.headline:after {
  content:"";
  background-color: #000;
  height: 10px;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <h1>blah blah blah</h1>
</div>
```

Or like this:

```css
.headline {
  width: 500px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  border:1px solid;
  background:linear-gradient(#000,#000) 0 50%/100% 10px  no-repeat;
}

h1 {
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <h1>blah blah blah</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because you added nice examples. You can also mention the use of `fieldset` with `legend` element.

Comment: @Vucko yes but we won't have a lot of flexibility with legend and fieldset

Comment: The `fieldset` element is for grouping sets of form fields together and not for line drawing. Also, the `legend` element's text is usually left-aligned, not centered, and this is very hard to style with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use responsive measurements to reach this, see the example below:

```css
.fullWidth{
width: 100vw;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullWidth"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this with fieldset and legend tag. This may not be the purpose of these tags but nothing prevents us to do things differently.

```css
div {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  height: 20px;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend align="center">Blah Blah Blah</legend>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/z364h1ar/